# Run a shell script with an html button

Tags: html, shell, button

I want to launch a bash script when a button is pressed on a website.
This is my first attempt:

```
<button type="button" onclick="/path/to/name.sh">Click Me!</button>
```

But no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you trying to run the script on the user's machine or on the server?

Comment: on the server. I'm running Debian

Comment: @Mat What about the case of running the script on the user's machine?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As stated by Luke you need to use a server side language, like php.
This is a really simple php example:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['run']) {
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
  exec("/path/to/name.sh");
}
?>

<!-- This link will add ?run=true to your URL, myfilename.php?run=true -->
<a href="?run=true">Click Me!</a>
```

Save this as `myfilename.php` and place it on a machine with a web server with php installed. The same thing can be accomplished with asp, java, ruby, python, ...

Comment: This answer works on my Ubuntu desktop with apache2 and php5 installed. Following is some additional information to help better understand this answer:    1. "myfilename.php" may be placed under the web server's root directory (DocumentRoot) which usually is "/var/www".    2. "myfilename.php" contains the above code, plus other HTML code.    3. The web client uses "<server name>/myfilename.php" as the HTTP address.

Comment: we don't php installed can it possible any other way like javascript. or without php install run this script.

Comment: Shell can also be a server-sided language. Why not just `case "${REQUEST_METHOD:-}/${QUERY_STRING:-}" in (GET/run=true) /path/to/name.sh;; esac`? Then let web server software call this, I guess.

Answer (score 13):

This is really just an expansion of BBB's answer which lead to to get my experiment working.

This script will simply create a file /tmp/testfile when you click on the button that says "Open Script".

This requires 3 files.

1. The actual HTML Website with a button.
2. A php script which executes the script
3. A Script

**The File Tree:**

```
root@test:/var/www/html# tree testscript/
testscript/
├── index.html
├── testexec.php
└── test.sh
```

**1. The main WebPage:**

```
root@test:/var/www/html# cat testscript/index.html
<form action="/testscript/testexec.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Open Script">
</form>
```

**2. The PHP Page that runs the script and redirects back to the main page:**

```
root@test:/var/www/html# cat testscript/testexec.php
<?php
shell_exec("/var/www/html/testscript/test.sh");
header('Location: http://192.168.1.222/testscript/index.html?success=true');
?>
```

**3. The Script :**

```
root@test:/var/www/html# cat testscript/test.sh

#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/testfile
```

Comment: if its possible to run the exe from sh file ? my environment is windows os. i want to execute the exe from browser i searched past three days nothing help me

Comment: Could you please expand on the need for `?success=true'` after the `.html` part on step 2? Maybe it can be removed?

Comment: @SOpalajodeArrierez I think your correct, its just there as example

Answer (score 7):

PHP is likely the easiest.

Just make a file `script.php` that contains `<?php shell_exec("yourscript.sh"); ?>` and send anybody who clicks the button to that destination. You can return the user to the original page with header:

```
<?php
shell_exec("yourscript.sh");
header('Location: http://www.website.com/page?success=true');
?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 6):

This is how it look like in pure bash

cat /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.cgi

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Content-type: text/html
echo ""
## make POST and GET stings
## as bash variables available
if [ ! -z $CONTENT_LENGTH ] && [ "$CONTENT_LENGTH" -gt 0 ] && [ $CONTENT_TYPE != "multipart/form-data" ]; then
read -n $CONTENT_LENGTH POST_STRING <&0
eval `echo "${POST_STRING//;}"|tr '&' ';'`
fi
eval `echo "${QUERY_STRING//;}"|tr '&' ';'`

echo  "<!DOCTYPE html>"
echo  "<html>"
echo  "<head>"
echo  "</head>"

if [[ "$vote" = "a" ]];then
echo "you pressed A"
  sudo /usr/local/bin/run_a.sh
elif [[ "$vote" = "b" ]];then
echo "you pressed B"
  sudo /usr/local/bin/run_b.sh
fi

echo  "<body>"
echo  "<div id=\"content-container\">"
echo  "<div id=\"content-container-center\">"
echo  "<form id=\"choice\" name='form' method=\"POST\" action=\"/\">"
echo  "<button id=\"a\" type=\"submit\" name=\"vote\" class=\"a\" value=\"a\">A</button>"
echo  "<button id=\"b\" type=\"submit\" name=\"vote\" class=\"b\" value=\"b\">B</button>"
echo  "</form>"
echo  "<div id=\"tip\">"
echo  "</div>"
echo  "</div>"
echo  "</div>"
echo  "</div>"
echo  "</body>"
echo  "</html>"
```

**Build with** https://github.com/tinoschroeter/bash_on_steroids

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Funny how this solution matches exactly the question, while the highest vote is not. Compliments to you Tino.