# How to embed script output file into HTML?

Tags: html, shell

I have a shell script which will generate the following output file.I would like to put the file in a html code..plz help me .my output looks like following

```
Sno.  Application               IPAddress     Status
----  -----------               ---------     ------
1     ManageDeviceAssociation   10.101.42.3   Up
2     ManagePlay                10.101.42.4   Up
3     ManageSettings            10.101.42.5   Up
4     SOLRUserProfileInfo       10.101.42.6   Up
5     SOLRPhysicalDeviceInfo    10.101.42.7   Up
```

Comment: could u plzz alobarate... as im new to html

Comment: see my edits give complete path in src.

Comment: what you want to execute script or html page....Please go google it....

Comment: @user3933685, This would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235785/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<embed>` tag for that.

```
<embed src="test.txt">
```

copy it in a test.html and open it in a browser.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<embed src="path/to/your/file/list.txt">

</body>
</html>
```

see it live [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed)