# run bash script from html

Tags: php, html, bash, nginx

I have read in several questions here how to run a bash script from html. Most of them referred me to php. [I followed everything in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235785/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button) but no go.
I don't have any experience with html or php.
So I set up everything as it should be (I think...).
I installed nginx (and its working fine).
I installed php and php-fpm.

My simple webpage is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My page</title>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="run.php">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My default nginx server config is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

I tried both options: With php5-cgi alone / With php5-fpm

My php script that should trigger on button click:

```
<?php
shell_exec("ls");
header('Location: https://www.google.com');
?>
```

But nothing happens (for now, I run just simple ls. when this will work i'll change it to some /path/script.sh)

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So as I mentioned before, I don't have any experience with html or php.

The problem was I separated the html and php  files. When combined, everything worked ok.

```
<?php
if ($_GET['run']) {
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
  exec("ls");
  header('Location: https://www.google.com');
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>My page</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- This link will add ?run=true to your URL, myfilename.php?run=true -->
<a href="?run=true">Click Me!</a>

</body>
</html>
```