# Run script from GET/POST action on nginx server

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, raspbian, webhooks, ifttt

Is there any way to run a script/program on a GET/POST action on a nginx server? I'm running public server with nginx on RasPi and would like to run a .py program via webhook. I got the secure server running but have hit a bit of a wall. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You would need to use a server side language like PHP. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235785/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button

Comment: Have a look at this page on Python and web servers: https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/webservers.html. 
This page may also be useful: https://cuasan.wordpress.com/2015/01/25/simple-cgi-web-app-testing-setup-with-python-cgi-and-nginxuwsgi/