# How can I run a program on my computer via web html server?

Tags: html

I want to **remotely run** some command-line program (no need for GUI) on a computer with a **web server** (Apache in my case) installed.

Some simple example program to start:

```
MyScript.sh -f file.txt
```

How could I do this?

As long as this could be considered a too broad question, I suggest narrowing it to (rather) simple programs, but allowing multiple ways to implement it, like HTML, JavaScript, CRON tweaks... etc.

Possible useful (but not strictly required) **features**:

- View outputted **results.**
- **Parameters** specification.

Further **notes**:

- Indeed, some methods could involve a bigger security risk. It is assumed, but it is still a good idea to consider it.

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language (e.g. Perl). Step 2: Pick a means to link the web server to it (e.g. Plack with FastCGI). Step 3: Write a wrapper around your command line program.

Comment: Flagging this as too broad... Even if **YOU** add a specific programming language Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @dustytrash , I can not select a programming language nor a linker to the web server (whatever that is), because I don't know which one could be used in this case. So I am posing the question. And I would say a programming site is a best site for this question than a generic or even a web design site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "Run a shell script with an html button" : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235785/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button

Answer (score 0):

A very basic method :

Create some **HTML file** on the web server to order your program startup:

```
# mkdir -p /usr/local/www/apache24/data/StartScripts
# echo "Program start requested" > /usr/local/www/apache24/data/StartScripts/index.html
```

Create this simple **script to check** if somebody did access that HTML file:

```
$ cat CheckScriptRequest.sh
tail /var/log/httpd-access.log | grep "GET /StartScripts/"
ScriptStartupRequest=$?
if (( ScriptStartupRequest == 0 ))
then
    MyScript.sh -f file.txt
fi
```

Program it as a **CRON entry**:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * CheckScriptRequest.sh
```

Now, when you will navigate to `http://yourdomain.com/StartScripts` , you will get a message "Program start requested", and your computer **will run** the program `MyScript.sh -f file.txt` (well, it will delay one minute until the CRON tab performs the check).

Of course, this simple proof of concept has multiple flaws and could be enhanced a lot.

Answer (score 0):

An example of the **CGI way** (extracted from [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/executing-linuxunix-commands-from-web-page-part-i.html)) that shows the classic "Hello World" and today's date (thanks to Vivek Gite):

Assuming the path to CGI executables (could change between versions) is `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` :

```
$ cd /usr/lib/cgi-bin
$ cat first.cgi

#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Bash as CGI"
echo "</title></head><body>"

echo "<h1>Hello world</h1>"
echo "Today is $(date)"

echo "</body></html>"
```

Setup **exe permission** on the script:

```
$ chmod +x first.cgi
```

Fire up your **web browser** and test the script navigating to:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/first.cgi
```

or remotely (open port, blah blah blah...):

```
http://your-ip/cgi-bin/first.cgi
```

Of course, you need **CGI support enabled** on your web server.