# How can I Execute NodeJS Server Client Side With Html Button Or Alternative If Not Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, socket.io

***Intro:*** Hello. So I started on a chat based social media app with Socket.io, but it seems like the client needs to open a localhost server to be able to communicate with the socket manager on my web API (node, express, socket.io).

***Question Tree***: Is it possible to make a nodejs server client side and execute a script with an html front end button so that the socket has a localhost to run tcp on to communicate to my web API? If so, how can I do this? If not, what are some alternatives to achieve the same results?

***conclusion:*** Any help is appreciated, I am learning how to do this sort of development for school and I just want some clarity. Thank you!

Comment: Why not open a web socket connection from the JavaScript in your HTML page to your server? It’s unclear why you think you need a separate local server in addition…

Comment: I found out how to do this earlier, but I reached another barrier and that is getting the name client sided to use in server sided javascript served to the user's dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you are on linux you have to make a bash script file that will run your app.js or index.js node file, for ex

```
node app.js
```

that will get executed when you press a button on page which again is easy if you use some server side language like php if you are interested here is the link for more[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235785/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button)

with just html its not possible easily its just too much of a task, just type that command in your terminal and you are good to go

rather you can make a script like bash in linux or bat in windows, that will open the server client side if you open that script file.

Comment: This will work but it's not user friendly having to download dependencies etc.