# Run a Bash Shell Script from HTML Hyperlink?

Tags: html, bash

I'm a Java Developer who is trying to learn HTML in painful baby steps.  I'd like my nacent website to run a simple bash shell script (or better yet, a PHP script) when the user clicks a button or hyperlink.  It is surprisingly hard to find a simple example of this!

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235785/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button) on StackOverflow.  The post's second answer lays out a step-by-step example, where the HTML code calls a PHP script; the PHP script calls a bash shell script.  I've tried to replicate the example on my own web server.  (FYI, I'm developing on an Ubuntu machine running Apache2.)

Here's my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form action="/testexec.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Run My Script">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Keeping it simple, this creates a button to call `testexec.php`, which is in the Apache home directory (`/var/www/html/`)  There's not much to that script, either:

```
<?php
shell_exec("/var/www/html/myBashScript.sh");
header('Location: http://10.10.10.10/myBashScript.sh?success=true');
?>
```

I'm not sure about those file pathnames.  Strictly speaking, `myBashScript.sh` is in directory `/var/www/html/` (although I suppose I could move it later).  When I troubleshoot, I can't tell if the pathnames are screwing up anything.  Also, I really hate that I have to refer to the server by its IP Address (here, `10.10.10.10`.)  There's gotta be a way to just say `localhost`, right?

Here's myBashScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "HELLO WORLD"
```

...and that should do it.  So I thought.  Both scripts are set properly with `chmod` and `chown` and `chgrp`, and I can manually run them without errors from the command line.

But when I surf to my webpage and click "Run My Script", I see this in my web browser:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "HELLO WORLD"
```

In other words, the text of the script is printed to the screen.  But I want the script to ***run*** and the output of the script to appear on screen.  Gah!  FWIW, I see no errors entered into the Apache2 error log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`), either.

Soooooo... anyone spot my error?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have PHP running properly on your server? You can test it by trying to run a simple test page with the content of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Also, in the script you posted, why run `shell_exec` and `header`?

Comment: You can't use `header()` if the script has already generated output.

Comment: Why are you trying to redirect to the bash script? You already executed it with `shell_exec()`, there's no need to go to it again.

Comment: If you want to execute a bash script directly, without going through PHP, put it in the `cgi-bin` directory and enable that feature in Apache.

Comment: You can leave out `http://10.10.10.10`, e.g. `Location: /myBashScript.sh`. When you omit this, it defaults to the same server as the original PHP URL.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks J!  You ask great questions.  Yes, your test PHP script shows that I'm running PHP v8.1.0.  The scripts I posted were taken verbatum and adapted from the other SO posting; that's why I'm running `shell_exec` and `header`.  I take it that this is a bad approach?

Comment: @Barmar Wow, you ask great questions!  My code is adapted from the other SO posting, which is prob why it looks so egregious to you.  So the `header()' might be tripping me up, huh?  That's very useful information.  If I put my myBashScript.sh in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` will I have to supply the pathname when calling it?  In my `serve-cgi-bin.conf` file, I've enabled LIB_CGI__BIN and listed that directory.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: yes, if you put it in cgi-bin, the url will be `/cgi-bin/myBasScript.sh`

Comment: @Barmar Excellent!  You rock!  I'll try this immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that could enable CGI scripts in your webserver, send the script to /cgi-bin/ folder, rename it to myscript.cgi (remember to put [the appropiate Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))), set 0755 permissions, correct owner/group and put in the very beginning of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
... more code...
```

The first echo line tells browser that the output of CGI script must be rendered as HTML (you could modify MIME type to your specific needs). There's a functional example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<title>TEST</title>"
echo "</head>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<h1>It Works!, Bash script running as CGI</h1>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

Comment: Excellent, yes this works great!  I'll need to study MIME types because I need the Bash Script to do other things beyond echo statements in HTML format.  But this is an excellent first step, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I really hate that I have to refer to the server by its IP Address (here, 10.10.10.10.) There's gotta be a way to just say localhost, right?

To reply to the question above, you can add the entry in /etc/hosts file in linux server.
for e.g.,
10.10.10.10 localhost localhost.localdomain